# Nearby place finiding Google MAP SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have used GOOGLE MAP SDK for ios instead of apple map in my applcation. I have gone through the google API calling to finding nearby resturants.But there is no mentions about how to use google api in Google MAP SDK for ios, Here my code,

```
-(void)loadView {
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:11.0183
                                                        longitude:76.9725
                                                             zoom:15];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView_;

mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
}
```

Where should i want to the google API to find nearby returants using

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@,%@&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",StrCurrentLatitude ,StrCurrentLongitude,@"2000",@"restaurant",kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

Please help me to solve it out!

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this issue?

Comment: This is reverse Geo-Coding, I just answered on forward geo-coding and its on similar lines --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949326/search-on-google-map-sdk/23952471#23952471

Answer (score -1):

In CLLocationManagerDelegate, function :

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

once u get the current location by 
currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

where, currentLocation is an instance of class CLLocation & locationManager is an instance of class CLLocationManager.

then u can hit the google API:

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%@,%@&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=false&key=%@",StrCurrentLatitude ,StrCurrentLongitude,@"2000",@"restaurant",kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

and manage the JSON response.. this worked for me.. :)